# Arrayformula that outputs the biggest value in a row

Tags: google-sheets

Need an Array Formula that outputs the biggest value in each row within the C4:E range with the assumption that new columns can be added inside C:E at any time with new values.

Here is a copy of my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c9vBShVK_iyxOelo1Dc0THVRJtP3U0pmiPcxbrLLSJ0/edit?pli=1#gid=1138197152

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with using [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013?hl=en) ??

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can try:

```
=BYROW(C5:E,LAMBDA(row,IF(COUNTA(row),MAX(row),)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Other method with byrow / map / let / lambda :

```
=BYROW(C5:E,
lambda(input,
   let(result,max(map(input,
      lambda(value,if(value="",-1,value)))),
      if(result=-1,"",result))
)
)
```

As requested, you can add a column between C:E without breaking the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
=ArrayFormula(LET(range, B5:E, header, "Your Header", return, BYROW(range, LAMBDA(r, IFERROR(MAX(FILTER(r, ISNUMBER(r)))))), {header; return} ))
```